# how to use random with variables in batch

Tags: batch-file

i need help with a text based game i am making i am trying to make a variable between the value of a variable and a certain number it is not working here is my code  `set damage=%random% %% %enemyattack%`
or `set damage=%random% %%%enemyattack%`
it keeps giving me huge negative number when i subtract it from my players health in a test file my whole code is:

```
@echo off
set health=100
set defense=3
set eattack=4
set damage=%random% %%%eattack%
set /a "damage1=damage*2"
set /a "health-damage1"
```

Answer (score 1):

try using the /a switch:

```
set /a damage=
```

Comment: thank you it worked!!

Comment: now it didn't work in my acctual program it worked in the tests but not the acctual program can you help me the only difference is that the program calls another program that has this in it exept for the sets